# Transitions in CSS when stop hoving

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi i would like some help about a site I am making. I want it smooth and simple but I need help about transitions when we are out of the hoving limit.
Here is my code working perfectly

```css
.NavBar a:hover 
{
    color:rgb(120, 176, 192);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

So i just need help to make an exit transition ! Thanks for your help ! <3

Comment: hello :) what do you mean by "exit transition"? this link may be help you https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `transition: 0.5s;` in the anchor rule (not hovered) instead of the `:hover` rule.

Because the rule only applies on hover... The transition delay is abruptly removed.

Here a snippet that may look like your issue:

```css
.NavBar{
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.NavBar a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}

.NavBar a:hover {
  color: rgb(120, 176, 192);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="NavBar">
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

Here a snippet where the transition is smooth:

```css
.NavBar{
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

.NavBar a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  transition: 0.5s; /* Have it here ! */
}

.NavBar a:hover {
  color: rgb(120, 176, 192);
}
```

```html
<div class="NavBar">
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your time !

Answer (score 1):

You always need to mention the property you want to transition.

```
transition : color 0.5s ;
```

or if you wanted all property to undergo transition

```
transition : all 0.5s;
```

In short **transition** is a short hand property of

**transition property**

**transition duration**

**transition timing function** -> make your transition smoother.

**transition delay**

```
transition : color /*<-property*/ 0.5s /*<-duration*/ linear /*<-timing function*/ 0.5s /*<-delay*/ ;
```